# Can I enable SSH on free version of VMware ESXi 4.0 without visiting datacenter?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I want to enable SSH on VMware ESXi 4.0 (free version). We don't have a console server connected to that host.

Is there any way I can enable SSH without visiting the data center? Their knowledge base [seems to indicate this is not possible](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003677).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to revert to evaluation mode, enable remote SSH tech support and then back to your free license?

Using the evaluation mode is great, it allows you to use some of the enterprise features for up to 60 (completely individual) days! :)

Comment: I had no idea that was possible. Will give it a try!

Comment: It's telling me evaluation mode has expired. Sounds like it's worth entering your free license key as soon as you install ESXi to preserve the evaluation mode days for when you may need them.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you can reach the server via vSphere client, you can go into settings, security profile, and start the SSH service. That's all there is to it.

Comment: The only options displayed on our ESXi 4.0 are :
* VMware vCenter Agent
* NTP Daemon

Comment: Hrmmm... perhaps this option only lights up after the host is being managed by vCenter or something. We typically turn on SSH immediately so we can verify some of the vSwitches are getting the right MTUs. I'll check in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

well... you should be able to enable SSH via vSphere in ESXI 4.0

- Go to **Configuration** tab
- Click on the left on **Advanced Settings**
- Click on the left on **VMkernel**
- Search for **VMkernel.Boot.techSupportMode**, enable it.
- Restart the server

According to the theory, that should enable the SSH...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not get "intelligent hands" at the DC to do it for you, directed by you?

Comment: Great idea but it's an unmanned DC. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SSH access of ESXi is unsupported, but very useful on some circumstances. It needs to access the physical console of the server to enable it. But it doesn't mean you need to travel there. Some servers has a web based management interface what provides access to the physical console of the server (iLO on HP servers, DRAC on DELL servers). But cheaper server's doesn't have. In that case, the datacenter's has the feature to provide access with IP based console. You should ask a time window and access from the provider to their IP console, and you can access the console of your server with it. I used it many times, they used to give this free.

Comment: You don't need access to the console to enable it, it can be enabled in Configuration -> Security profile -> Services -> Properties